# Настоящий поток газа

Tags: физика, культура

Я работаю с многими русскими клиентами.  У нас тут в США привычка отличать в сообщениях ACFM (actual cubic feet per minute, фактические кубические футы в минуту) от SCFM (standard cubic feet per minute, кубические футы при определенных условиях в минуту).

У каждая культура свои обычаи.  Насколько я знаю, международная система единиц не определяет использование приставки "N", вместе упомянутый выше "S", который обозначает, что величина при определенных условиях.  Эту приставку используют всемирно.  А что насчет приставки "A"?  Строго говоря, зависит от культуры.  Используют ли эту приставку, или просто лишение приставки обозначает, что величина при настоящих условиях?

Comment: Your Russian is ungrammatical and uses the technical terms wrongly so it is incomprehensible. Can you ask the same in English? Do you mean нормальные условия or текущие условия? Настоящие условия sounds just wrong (in Russian it would mean non-fake conditions, I doubt you meant that). Also, overall your phrasing is ungrammatical and incomprehensible so it is difficult to tell what you are asking about.

Comment: "standard conditions" and "actual conditions" would be *нормальные условия* and *рабочие условия*. However, it's not clear what is it that you're asking. The two abbreviations you have mentioned define two distinct physical quantities with same dimensions (volume to time ratio), but SI does not deal with quantities, it deals with units, and those units in SI would be cubic meters per second in both cases. There might be some standards on this, but they are definitely not regulated by SI.

Comment: Спасибо за критики.  Вопрос не о том, какие единицы используют в РФ.  Вопрос простой: есть ли приставка, соответствующая к приставке "А", и как широко используется?

Answer (score 1):

Газовая отрасль Российской Федерации при расчётах с потребителями использует атмосферные условия по ГОСТ 2939—63:
температура +20° С (293,15 К);
давление 760 мм рт. ст. (101 325 Н/м²);
влажность равна 0.

Стандартные условия это температура 0° С, давление 100 000 Н/м²

Использование единиц измерения зависит от общепринятых норм в конкретной отрасли. Я думаю, что указываются кубометры в минуту и условия: стандартные (они же нормальные), или те что по ГОСТу. Сомневаюсь, что у нас используются кубические футы или какие-либо приставки, указывающие на атмосферные условия.

Comment: у нас скорее всего действительно не используются кубические футы, но все приведённые вами измерения вообще не про то, так что это просто вообще не ответ.

Comment: @shabunc Тут не совсем понятно, про что вообще вопрос. Возможно, что как раз про то, какие у нас приняты условия помимо "стандартных".

Comment: Спасибо за ГОСТ!

Answer (score 1):

Brief googling shows us that vacuum equipment engineers in Russia use *л/мин (литры в минуту)* and *нл/мин (нормолитры в минуту)* which I believe correspond to your ACFM and SCFM with appropriate coefficients.

This (in no way authoritative) [link](http://www.smc-pneumatik.ru/gb.php?uid=15341) says:

> "Нл/мин", как и "норм.л/мин", "l/min (ANR)" - обозначают расход воздуха, выраженный в так называемых "нормальных" литрах в минуту. Это значит, что количество воздуха выражено в виде объема, который занимал бы этот воздух при атмосферном давлении и температуре 20 градусов Цельсия. Эти условия регламентированы стандартами ГОСТ 2939-63 и ISO 8778. Иногда можно встретить обозначение "л/мин". Если при этом специально не оговаривается, при каких условиях выражен объем воздуха, это можно понимать так, что ссылка на "нормальные" условия просто опущена (по небрежности или для краткости), но имеются в виду именно эти условия. Тогда отличия между "нл/мин" и "л/мин" нет.

Anyway, Russian standards require that all unit names and abbreviations are transliterated, so Russian does not use W, l or mm Hg, but rather *Вт, л* and *мм. рт. ст. (миллиметр ртутного столба)*. So neither N nor S could be used as prefixes in Russian unit abbreviations.